# How to show two random variables have the same distribution?

Tags: probability

Let $\{X_n\}$ and $\{Y_n\}$ be sequences of random variables such that the pairs $(X_i,X_j)$ and $(Y_i,Y_j)$ have the same distributions for all $i,j$. If $X_n \rightarrow X$ in probability, show that $Y_n$ converges in probability to some limit $Y$ having the same distribution

I am trying to prove it in the following steps:

Step1: Show that $P(|Y_n-Y_m|> \epsilon) = P(|X_n-X_m|> \epsilon)$ for arbitrary $\epsilon > 0$. This is true since $(X_i,X_j)$ and $(Y_i,Y_j)$ have the same distributions for all $i,j$.

Step2: $X_n \rightarrow X$ in probability implies $X_n$ is Cauchy convergent in probability(meaning that for all $\epsilon >0 $, $P(|X_n-X_m|> \epsilon)$ goes to zero as m,n go to $\infty$). So $Y_n$ is Cauchy convergent in probability as well.

Step3: Show that there exists a random variable $Y$ such that $Y_n \rightarrow Y$ in probability. Actually, $Y(\omega) = \lim_{k\rightarrow \infty} Y_{n_k}(\omega)$ for a subsequence such that $P(|Y_{n_k} - Y_{n_{k+1}} | > \epsilon) \leq 2^{-k}$. And we can show $Y_n \rightarrow Y$ in probability using Borel Cantelli Lemma.

Step4: Show $Y$ have the same distribution as $X$.

I am having trouble about Step4. So do $(X_i,X_j)$ and $(Y_i,Y_j)$ have the same distributions imply $X_n$ and $Y_n$ are identically distributed?

Comment: If would be helpful if you post step 1,2 and 3.

Comment: I appreciate that you´ve  added your approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(X_n,X_{n+1}) \to (X,X)$ in probability and $(Y_n,Y_{n+1}) \to (Y,Y)$ in probability. Hence $(X,X)$ has same distribution as $(Y,Y)$ which implies that $X$ has the same distribution a $Y$.

Comment: So if you have $X_n\rightarrow X$ and $Y_n\rightarrow Y$ in probability, and $X_n$ and $Y_n$ have the same distribution, then $X$ and $Y$ have the same distribution. I am trying to use DCT to show $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}P(X_n \in B) = P(X\in B)$ for all Borel set B.  But this is not so trivial to me. Can you please explain a bit more?

Comment: @J.Li You cannot prove that for  every Borel set. Convergence in probability implies weak convergence which only tells you that $P(X_n \in B) \to P(X \in B$ when veer  the boundary of the Borel set $B$  is a continuity set for the distribution of $X$ (in the sense $P(X \in \partial B)=0$.

Comment: Yeah that's where I have problem. But to show $X$ and $Y$ are identically distributed we have to show for all Borel sets(or at least sets like $(-\infty, x]$). My question is, how did you show  $X$ has the same distribution as $Y$? Here I restate [the problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3470593/limit-behavior-of-two-identically-distributed-sequences)

Comment: @J.Li If two distributions are equal on a dense set they are equal everywhere (by right continuity).  If Two probabilty measures $P$ and $Q$ are equal on Borel sets which are continuous sets for one of the measures then they are automatically equal on all Borel sets.