# Limit behavior of two identically distributed sequences.

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory

Let $\{X_n\}$ and $\{Y_n\}$ be two random variable sequences such that $X_n $ and $Y_n$ are identically distributed for each n and $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} X_n = X$ and $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} Y_n = Y$ in probability. How to show that X and Y are identically distributed?

I am thinking of using DCT to show(this may not be the correct way) $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}P(X_n \in B) = P(X\in B)$$ for all Borel sets B. But I fail to show $1_{\{X_n\in B\}}$ goes to $1_{\{X\in B\}}$ in probability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$P(X_n \leq x)\to P(X \leq x)$ whenever $P(X=x)=0$ and $P(Y_n \leq x)\to P(Y \leq x)$ whenever $P(Y=x)=0$ because convergence in probability implies convergence in distribution. Hence $P(X=x)=P(Y=x)$ except at countably many points. This implies that $P(X=x)=P(Y=x)$ except  on  a dense set.  If $F$ and $G$ are two distribution functions such that $F(x)=G(x)$ on a dense set they are  equal at all points by right continuity.